# One way locking mechanism linear movement

Tags: design, gears, steel, mechanisms, friction

Sorry for the English in advance, it is not my native language :)

I am working on a design which involves moving two steel plates in a horizontal linear motion together to clamp around a box. After this movement is done it must not be able to undo this movement. So it becomes a one-way movement with automatic lock. The force it has to whistand is in the order of 5000 kg. It must rely on a form closing mechanism. It can not rely on friction since it is a safety lock. But must be able to continue getting tighter when it is allowed (space might get narrower over time and changing forces must only be able to move it tighter). Adjustability is the main trouble. Has to be able to clamp/lock in 1cm (0.4 inch) increments (or narrower).

Fabrication/material: All the other components will be made using a water jet cutter to cut steel plate in various shapes. Assembly can be done by welding but is not preferred. Milling, drilling/ using a lathe is all good.

I have looked at a linear ratchet system (with teeth and paw or hole and pawl) which is the basic principle of completing this task. But here lies the problem of the adjustability, it has to be adjustable in a maximum of 1cm (0.4 inch) increments. But I think to myself that there has to be a simpler way to do it. Maybe there is none but maybe i am looking at it blindstaring at the ratchet mechanism and there is a mechanism that i completely look over. So do you guys know any system which can do this task?

Thank you for any awnser in advance!

Comment: Diagrams always help with these types of questions. Firstly they reinforce your ideas, but they assist others in trying to understand what you have in mind. By the way, your English is excellent.

Comment: Use a ratchet but have 2, 3 or more because of the load you mention they will not be small and that way if the ratchet needs 10cm to operate then several staggered will provide a smaller increment.

Comment: I would make use a 2 link bar mechanism. As the mechanism becomes straight mechanical advantage goes to infinity. Then let it move to overcenter position and block that direction. The same mechanism is being used in landing gears of aircrafts so it does work.